# How do I get elements from list of lists based on a index value using python?

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, indexing, key

I have lists of lists like this :

```
Input_list= [['a','b'],[1,6],[1,13.8]]
```

I have a dictionary

```
dictny={'a':'mdl/a','b':'mdl/b'}
```

I am trying to find whether keys present in dictny will be present in Input_list or not by using following code:

```
Key_list=[]
for key,value in dictny.iteritems():
    Key_list.append(key)
```

Here I am appending all keys into a separate list.

```
for key in Key_list:
    for indx,list in enumerate(Input_list):
        for element_indx,element in enumerate(list):
            if element == key:
                print "matching key",element
                print "element_index",element_indx
```

Here I am trying to find whether my key is present in Input_list or not and I am trying to catch the index of the matching element. Now I want to use this index and to extract corresponding elements from sublist of Input_list based on the element_indx. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the output supposed to be?

Comment: since both dictionary and Input_list have a and b as comment elements, the index would be 0 and 1.So I need and output which would be a list ,for suppose named as zero_index_element_list=[1,1], first_index_element_list=[6,13.8]

Comment: So what if the input list was `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]` ?

Comment: No my input list format will be same all the time atleast for now.